# IScreen.Router.Navigate.Execute not working with ReactiveUI 7 on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I have a Xamarin.Forms project here with RxUI 6.5.2 and a very simple navigation using the Router and it's working:

https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/RoutingSimpleSample/tree/ReactiveUI_6_5

But the (almost) same code isn't working with RxUI 7: 
https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/RoutingSimpleSample/tree/master

Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong or if this is some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed to me by @kentcb here https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1166

> Execute returns IObservable, and is lazy. You must subscribe to it
>   for anything to happen.

So I updated the project and now it works perfectly!